# How to DIsable Image Caption on Hover in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, hover, caption

Sometimes ago I found a Site, URL is http://www.fun71.com i saw that when i bring mouse to the image than image cation is hide. can someone tells he how can i do this with my site ?
is is done by CSS or by Javascript ? If it is CSS than please code for me. my Friend Gives e CSS which is

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

but it is not working for me. plz help me

Comment: It totally depends on your HTML elements, their id or classes. Please provide your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all your image captions have the wp-caption-text class then simply hide the text on hover as below.

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
font-size: 0.8em;
line-height: 17px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px 0px 5px;
background-color: #FFF;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
opacity: 0.7;
display:block;
```

}

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text:hover{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:
Removing the image title visible on hover by adding this to the theme functions.php

```
// Title Removal from WordPress image
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'remove_image_text');
function remove_image_text( $attr ) {
unset($attr['title']);
return $attr;
}
```

[Source](https://www.webzando.com/blog/remove-hide-title-wordpress-images/)